# Sending emails with bcc and cc with wp_mail

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I want to send the following fields to wp_mail

[image]

If i put all the emails in `Email to`,`Copy to` and `Bcc to` in an array `$emails` and pass it to wp_mail.  How do i set the headers for cc and bcc  in wp_mail?

```
$headers = 'From: Test <info@test.co.uk>' . '\r\n';
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html\r\n'; 
$success = wp_mail( $emails, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Have you tried by creating an array and defining them into it ?

Comment: show the format of `$emails`

Comment: `$emails` is simply an array of email address.  I don't know how to set headers cc and bcc for the emails in the array.

Comment: @user892134 I want this functionality. Can you please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 46):

You can use an array to send all the info you need, thus:

```
$headers[] = 'From: Test <info@test.co.uk>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: copy_to_1@email.com';
$headers[] = 'Cc: copy_to_2@email.com';
...
$headers[] = 'Bcc: bcc_to_1@email.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: bcc_to_2@email.com';
$success = wp_mail( $emails, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

You can get it programmatically, being `$copy_to` and `$bcc_to` arrays of said form fields after splitting them by the comma you state in the inner field text, and having defined array `$headers`:

```
$headers[] = 'From: Test <info@test.co.uk>';
foreach($copy_to as $email){
    $headers[] = 'Cc: '.$email;
}
foreach($bcc_to as $email){
    $headers[] = 'Bcc: '.$email;
}
$success = wp_mail( $emails, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

These work because `wp_mail()` doesn't trust you, so normalizes and concatenates multiple `Cc:` and `Bcc:` headers correctly. [The RFC spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6) mandates that these headers occur only once, with multiple recipients comma-separated, and "folded" if the lines are too long, so it wouldn't work in plain PHP.

Comment: What about $emails? is it going to be an array of all the users email or what? I am trying with all the users in that $emails array but it is showing all the users in the To list.

Comment: @NewUser you can leave the $emails as empty string i.e  ``wp_mail('', $subject, $message, $headers));``