# Having trouble sending an email to Cc using wp_mail() in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am able to send the email with no issues, but the email is not being CC'd even after I am inputting this in the headers argument.  Am I missing something in my code below?

```
$to = 'myemail@example.com';

$subject = 'This email came from the site!';

$headers = array(
     'Content-type: text/html',
     'Cc: otheremail@example.com',
);

$body = $_POST['message'];
$response = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Comment: please visit here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098670/sending-emails-with-bcc-and-cc-with-wp-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098670/sending-emails-with-bcc-and-cc-with-wp-mail)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that I needed to add the cc email in my array in this format

`Alias Name <otheremail@example.com>`

instead of just the email

`otheremail@example.com`.

Now, the email is being cc'd properly.

Complete working sample.

```
$to = 'myemail@example.com';

$subject = 'This email came from the site!';

$headers = array(
     'Content-type: text/html',
     'Cc: Alias Name <otheremail@example.com>',
);

$body = $_POST['message'];
$response = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Comment: Note to lurkers - ensure that you have sanitized the $_POST['message'] before using it.  (Never trust the content of $_POST variables without sanitizing them.)