# How can i hide the recipient list from wp_mail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to hide the recipient list? In the email everyone can see who other got the email, i'd like them to see only themselves as recipients

```
 $email = array();
 array_push($email, $user_info - > user_email);
 $uni = array();
 $uni = array_unique($email);
 /* var_dump($uni);
  exit;*/
 wp_mail($uni, $subject, $message);
 //  wp_mail( 'admin mail', $subject, $message );
```

The full code is this, i send an email for every new post to all users that are part of a membership plan that resctricts 1 or more categories of a post.
If in the post a certain category is selected of which a user is part of from the membership plan, the user will receive an email notification :

```
//Function to change email address
/*function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
return 'mail from';
}
//Function to change sender name
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
return 'mail from name';
}
// Hooking up our functions to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name' );*/
function post_unpublished( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
//initialize the function when a post is published
if ( $old_status != 'publish'  &&  $new_status == 'publish' ) { 
//grab post ID                   
$post_id = $post->ID; 
//get all users                  
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
$email = array(); 
//grab post URL
$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );   
//set email subject                    
$subject = 'Tst Posts';   
//set email content                
$message = "A new post came out:\n\n";
$message .= $post->post_title . ": " . $post_url;  
//grab post rules
$rules = wc_memberships()->get_rules_instance()->get_post_content_restriction_rules( $post_id );    
foreach($users as $user_id){ 
//grab the ID of every user
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id->ID);
$args = array( 'status' => array( 'active' ));
//get active memberships of the user
$plans = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $user_info, $args ); 
$user_plans = array();
//grab ID of the membership plans
foreach($plans as $plan){
array_push($user_plans,$plan->plan_id);                  
}               
foreach($rules as $rule){                       
if(in_array($rule->get_membership_plan_id(), $user_plans)){
//grab email of users
if ( ! empty( $plans ) ) {
array_push($email,$user_info->user_email);
}   
}
}                                                                            
}
//merge identical emails since same user may be on multiple categories
$uni=array();                           
$uni=array_unique($email);     
$headers .= 'Bcc: '. implode(",", $uni) . "\r\n";
wp_mail( null, $subject, $message, $headers );
// wp_mail( 'admin mail', $subject, $message );                          
}
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'post_unpublished', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You mean a BCC?

Comment: yes, i tried it like this:
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $uni) . "\r\n";
wp_mail( null, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
but it shows the "to" empty on email

Comment: have you tried using correct case? `Bcc` instead of `BCC` ?

Comment: yes, i tried with Bcc too ,but on email still the 'to' is empty although the user does receive it

Comment: in that case please provide the full code you're currently using, in your question there's no BCC mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers[] = 'From: Test <info@test.co.uk>';

$headers[] = 'Cc: copy_to_1@email.com';
$headers[] = 'Cc: copy_to_2@email.com';

$headers[] = 'Bcc: bcc_to_1@email.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: bcc_to_2@email.com';

$success = wp_mail( $emails, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400815/1117368)